# In app purchases in iTunes Connect. How to make the in app purchase "Cleared for sale"?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I am trying to add in app purchases to an app that is already for sale on the app store for the next update. I have never added any in app purchases to it before.

I am using MKStoreKit to handle the in app purchases so I figure everything is as it should be on the coding side of things.

When my app starts up I query the list of available in app purchases, this successfully returns the list of in app purchases (just two at the moment) and the prices of them.

I have a button in my app that sends a purchase request, I pass in the appropriate product ID. This consistently gets cancelled every time and I get the error message

> User cancelled transaction:

in the log.

From reading other blogs and posts I have come to the conclusion that it is because my in app purchases aren't cleared for sale in iTunes connect, they currently say "Waiting for Review".

I have tried everything on this check list to try get this to work http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/ but still nothing.

I submitted an app and then a few hours later developer rejected it because I heard this worked for some people.

Anybody know how I make the in app purchases cleared for sale in iTunes Connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just spotted that I never closed this question. The reason this was happening was because Apples servers were acting up at the time. Game center sandbox was also effected at the time. I left it alone for a couple of days and it started working when I got back to it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should have tested the in-app before submitting them for review. Afaik, as soon as they are in-review state, purchases with the test account might not work. You could try and create another in-app item for testing purposes, just create it and try to purchase that (using your iTunes Connect Test account) without submitting it for review.

The cleared for sale status can be set in the pricing and availability section of the respective in-app item.

Comment: Releasing a binary was the last thing I tried, I was getting the same issue before that. I have developer rejected it and I still get the same error. The cleared for sale option was ticked all along in itunes connect, so that can't be the issue either.