# In-App Purchases still Waiting for Review

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

When we developed a new version of our app, we submitted new versions of some in-app purchases, which were the same as the old versions but consumable (so you can purchase them multiple times) and also to support a discount.

They were returned with a reason like "please submit together with the binary".

So we submitted them again after uploading the binary for the new app version.

The binary was reviewed and Approved. It is now Pending Developer Release.

But the new in-app purchases are still yellow and In Review!

However, when clicking on them, a checkmark in the page says "Cleared for Sals."

We are worried that if we release the new version of the app, people will go to purchase and won't see the new purchases, ruining our chance to offer the new purchases -- as very few people return to a purchases page just for the fun of it, and so all existing users will just choose from whatever is there now (the old purchases) and come away none the wiser.

Has anyone had this? Can you confirm 100% that Cleared for Sale is all you need *even if* we have a yellow status and app is In Review? Apple documentation seems to suggest that this status means we have to wait until the review has been completed. But they already reviewed the app, so this may be just a UX bug and we could be stuck waiting for nothing??

If you have had a similar experience with the App Store reviews, please advise us in an answer.

Comment: Related questions can suggest that in addition to this issue, apps may be released without in-app purchases being available. How to prevent this situation and make sure they are available first? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405431/in-app-purchases-in-itunes-connect-how-to-make-the-in-app-purchase-cleared-for

Comment: If your iap are still in review then they will not be available in your app. You need to wait until they are reviewed before releasing your new app version

Comment: @GregoryMagarshak Did you request expedition review, and resend new binary file?

Answer (score 17):

From my personal experience: **do not release new version until 24 hours pass from In-App Purchase has approved**.

I had such problem: IAP was approved (green) and new version was released at the same day (by expedited review). Whole day users had claiming that they can't buy product. App hadn't getting this IAP from Apple server (as others IAPs in this app worked). Apple support recommended just wait for 24 hours. When 24 hours passed from IAP was approved, this IAP became available for purchase.

Answer (score 0):

I would confirm with the review team. You can request an expedited review https://developer.apple.com/contact/app-store/?topic=expedite

Comment: I just didn't want to waste a request for an expedited review. But there is another topic which I used to submit an issue, namely "more info" about review status.

Comment: It sounds like it's a problem with their system, so I would remind them that it shouldn't be counted. They will probably make you do this anyway, and it's probably the quickest way to get a response in any case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are alright. I've had the outer page get stuck in a review status that wasn't correct, then when clicked into the inner one it had the correct status. I believe it is just an iTunes connect bug but don't quote me on it.

Comment: Almost 3 years and this bug still exists. 3 years and Apple doesn't care about appstore connect.

Comment: OK, I found out how to fix this stupid bug.

If you see your IAP item is "In review", click the details and add a small change (add a dot) in the description so it will force the status to be updated. After a few seconds you will see your IAP is approved. You can then revert your change.

Answer (score 0):

"Cleared for Sale" is the *developer* side of whether an In-App Purchase is available. The current contextual help in App Store Connect for this states:

> Select the checkbox to make your in-app purchase available on the App
>   Store after approval.

The "after approval" indicates that for an In-App Purchase to be accessible to customers, it must be both approved by App Store review, and cleared for sale by the developer. The App Store review for the In-App Purchase occurs separately from the review of the app itself, and could potentially be completed before or after when the app binary is reviewed.

As a developer, you therefore have two choices:

1. Set up your app to modify the interface displayed to the user, depending on the In-App Purchases that are currently available in the store. This way, you can release the app update before any new In-App Purchases have been approved, and you can also (potentially, if your app architecture supports it) upload and release further new In-App Purchases without updating the app binary.
2. Set your app update to be manually released by the developer. It will then be held in *Pending Developer Release* status after review, and you can wait until the new In-App Purchase products have also been approved before releasing the app.

Comment: So, according your answer, if app was released, But my in-app was rejected. and after fix in-app (in-app just wasn't configured by backend when binary app was in review), in-app is still waiting for review. Should I resend binary file for the review? Or should just I wait review only in-apps without resend binary file?

Comment: Little bit unsure re your situation here, but if you’re saying the current binary in the store is ready to correctly handle the in app purchase, then you can leave the binary alone, and just wait for the in app purchase to be reviewed.

Comment: Thank you, I will hope that the in-app purchase will be reviewed as quickly as possible.

Comment: Good news, Today in-apps were reviewed. Time from start "waiting for review" to "approved" was about 30 hours. In-apps contains many languages. And binary file was not resend.