# Can't get Apple to review my in-app purchases

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect, apple-developer

I am unable to get the Apple Review team to look at my in-app purchases.

- I have an already published app with some IAPs. I'm trying to add a few new ones now.
- I've uploaded a new binary and submitted that to review along with the in-app purchases.
- Upon the first try, my app was approved, but the IAPs were returned with: "In order to approve your new in-app purchase business model, we have to verify the purchasability of the items being sold."
- I removed the already approved binary and submitted it again to review along with the IAPs, because I read somewhere else in this forum that having both the IAPs and the app "In review" at the same time will somehow get them to look at it.
- The app was approved again, the IAPs were "in review" for 3 days, and then they got returned again but this time the message is:

"We have returned your in-app purchase products to you as the required binary was not submitted. When you are ready to submit the binary, please resubmit the in-app purchase products with the binary."

I have specifically asked them in my review notes to also review the IAPs and provided them with a sandbox account to test.

At this point, how to get them to finally look at and approve my IAPs is beyond my comprehension.

Should I submit the IAPs first, get them approved, then submit the binary?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In-App Purchases still Waiting for Review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42800274/in-app-purchases-still-waiting-for-review)

Comment: Unfortunately not, the OP here had their IAPs cleared for sale after submitting together with the binary, mine is returned with “required binary was not submitted”, while actually it was submitted.